# How to customize string root in PhisicalFilePRovider initialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core 2.2 web application, in Start-Up class, in Configure method, i set the use of static files, mapping a specified disk folder, instancing a file provider thus: 
`FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\business\ROM\documents\112233\")`
like in this code:

using ...

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\business\ROM\documents\112233\"),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/dexml")
            });

            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When i list my etntities, in the foreach cycle in the view i link the documents thus:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/dexml/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomefile)">view document</a>
```

All works fine!
But i need to set PhisicalFileProvider string root with placeholder, like this:
`FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\business\[code1]\documents\[code2]\")`
and i associated code1 and code2 in custom asp.net user identity fields.

How i can set FileProvider string root with placeholder and replace it in same place with user attributes?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For `PhysicalFileProvider`, it will be initialized while calling `app.UseStaticFiles` and could not changed during runtime.

You need to implement your own middleware to serve static files dynamically.

```
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.Map("/dexml", subApp => {
        subApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {                    
            await next();
            var userName = context?.User?.Identity?.Name;
            if (userName != null)
            {
                var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
                using (var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider($@"D:\{ user.Code1 }\{ user.Code2 }"))
                {
                    var filePath = context.Request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
                    var info = provider.GetFileInfo(filePath);
                    using (var stream = info.CreateReadStream())
                    {
                        var originalStream = context.Response.Body;
                        await stream.CopyToAsync(originalStream);
                        context.Response.Body = stream;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```